# How to get cpu usage and memory usage graph of server during jmeter load test running through Jenkins

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to measure CPU and Memory usage of my server during load test using Jmeter.
For this i added "jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector" listener with my scripts in jmeter GUI and configured jmeter perfmon plugin in my server. I got the graph in jmeter GUI correctly without any errors.

Now i want to run my same jmeter script via Maven and jenkins for continuous Integration (Without opening jmeter GUI).

My question is,
How can i see the CPU and memory usage of the server in graph without opening jmeter GUI after test execution completes.

Is it possible to generate CPU and Memory graph once my test script completes execution in Jenkins? If so please guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the JMeter plugin tools.
There is a commandline utility here: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/ which is capable of generating images. These can be shown in Jenkins.

Another useful link can be found here: https://github.com/codecentric/jmeter-graph-maven-plugin (there is a link to a blog there too, but that is in German).

Hope it helps you in the right direction.

Edit: I used loadosophia.org in the past to generate reports.